# How to prove the function is a fundamental solution of the operator?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Show that the function $u(x_1,x_2)=\left\{\!\! \begin{aligned} & \frac{1}{2}, if \left| {x_1  - \xi _1 } \right| < \xi _2  - x_2 \\ &0,otherwise \end{aligned} \right.$ is a fundamental solution of $L=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_2^2}-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1^2}$ at the pole $\xi=(\xi_1,\xi_2)$.

Need to show $Lu=\delta_(\xi_1,\xi_2)$. Choose arbitrary $\phi \in C_0^2(\Omega)$ (0 means compact support,$\Omega$ means the nozero domain of u), $$\int_\Omega \phi Lu dx=\int_\Omega ({\tilde L}\phi) udx=1/2\int_\Omega(-1)^2L\phi dx=1/2\int_\Omega(\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x_2^2}-\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x_1^2})dx_1 dx_2=1/2\int_{\partial \Omega} (-\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_2}dx_1 - \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_1}dx_2)$$, how to show the last integral equals to $\phi(\xi_1,\xi_2)$?

Thanks!